# Where do I add a main method so that I can run this program properly?

Tags: java, methods, main-method

I don't know where to add the main method so I can run this class. Help! I'm not sure about where to put the main method either.

This class manages a hair salon. Global variables are used to keep track of dailyRevues (total $ coming in), dailyTax (total tax amount) and the number of hair cuts, permanents and colorings. Also, the number of customers who have been serviced is to be kept track of A daily report is to be printed which gives the total number of customers, the total number of hair cuts, permanents and colorings. Also, the total amount of revenue (money taken in) and tax needs to be printed in the daily report. Finally, the average amount of money spent by each customer should be calculated and printed in the report. If the store brings in $650 or more, then the store manager receives 5% of the daily total revenue as a bonus. You should include the store manager bonus in your report and subtract it from the total revenue to give the net revenue for the day. Feel free to add additional variables and methods as you deem necessary

> Here is My Code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salon {


See example report*/
//Globals
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int hairCuts = 0;
int permanents = 0;
int colorings = 0;
int customers = 0;

double dailyRev = 0;
double total = 0;
double dailyTax = 0;
double bonus; //money due the manager if certain conditions are met

final double COSTHC = 20;  //Cost of HairCut
final double COSTPERM = 50;  //Cost of Permanent
final double COSTCOLORING = 60;  //Cost of Coloring
final double COSTHC_PERM = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Permanent
final double COSTCOL_PERM = (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Perm and Coloring
final double COSTHC_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Coloring
final double COSTHC_PERM_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Cut, Perm and Color




public void menu() {
    //preconditions:  none
    //postconditions: the correct method is called depending on the user's
    //input, totalValues are updated appropriately
    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.println("---------MENU---------");
        System.out.println("1 =  Reset Daily Totals");
        System.out.println("2 =  Haircut Only");
        System.out.println("3 =  Permanent Only");
        System.out.println("4 =  Coloring Only");
        System.out.println("5 =  Haircut and Coloring");
        System.out.println("6 =  Haircut and Permanent");
        System.out.println("7 =  Permanent and Coloring");
        System.out.println("8 =  Haircut, Permanent and Coloring");
        System.out.println("9 =  Print Daily Report");
        System.out.println("10 = Exit");

        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice == 10) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (choice == 1) {
            resetTotals();

        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            hairCuts++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Haircut only: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            permanents++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTPERM;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Permanent only: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 4) {
            colorings++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOLORING;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Coloring only: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 5) {
            hairCuts++;
            colorings++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_COL;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Haircut and Coloring: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 6) {
            hairCuts++;
            permanents++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Haircut and Permanent: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 7) {
            permanents++;
            colorings++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOL_PERM;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("Coloring and Permanent: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 8) {
            hairCuts++;
            colorings++;
            permanents++;
            customers++;
            dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM_COL;
            dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
            total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
            System.out.println("haircut, Coloring, and Permanent: $");
            System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
            System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
            System.out.println("Total: $" + total);

        }
        if (choice == 9) {
            printReport();
        }
    } while (true);
}

public void resetTotals() {
    hairCuts = 0;
    permanents = 0;
    colorings = 0;
    customers = 0;
    dailyRev = 0;
    dailyTax = 0;
}

public void printReport() {
    if (customers == 0) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Daily Report for Salon");
    System.out.println("Number of Customers: $" + customers);
    System.out.println("Number of Hair Cuts: $" + hairCuts);
    System.out.println("Number of Permanents: $" + permanents);
    System.out.println("Number of Colorings: $" + colorings);

    System.out.println("Average amount spent per customer(Not including Tax): $" + (total / customers));
    System.out.println("Total Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
    System.out.println("Total Tax: $" + dailyTax);
    if (dailyRev >= 650) {
        System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $" + (dailyRev * 0.05));
        System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + 1.05 * dailyRev);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $0");
        System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. \-_-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, everything is a class. Main methods are written inside the class as such:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

In your case that'd be:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salon {
    /* See example report */
    //Globals
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int hairCuts = 0;
    int permanents = 0;
    int colorings = 0;
    int customers = 0;
    
    double dailyRev = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double dailyTax = 0;
    double bonus; //money due the manager if certain conditions are met
    
    final double COSTHC = 20;  //Cost of HairCut
    final double COSTPERM = 50;  //Cost of Permanent
    final double COSTCOLORING = 60;  //Cost of Coloring
    final double COSTHC_PERM = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Permanent
    final double COSTCOL_PERM = (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Perm and Coloring
    final double COSTHC_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Coloring
    final double COSTHC_PERM_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Cut, Perm and Color
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salon s = new Salon();
        s.menu();
        // add your code here
    }
    
    public void menu() {
        //preconditions:  none
        //postconditions: the correct method is called depending on the user's
        //input, totalValues are updated appropriately
        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("---------MENU---------");
            System.out.println("1 =  Reset Daily Totals");
            System.out.println("2 =  Haircut Only");
            System.out.println("3 =  Permanent Only");
            System.out.println("4 =  Coloring Only");
            System.out.println("5 =  Haircut and Coloring");
            System.out.println("6 =  Haircut and Permanent");
            System.out.println("7 =  Permanent and Coloring");
            System.out.println("8 =  Haircut, Permanent and Coloring");
            System.out.println("9 =  Print Daily Report");
            System.out.println("10 = Exit");
    
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 10) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
    
            if (choice == 1) {
                resetTotals();
    
            }
            if (choice == 2) {
                hairCuts++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 3) {
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTPERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Permanent only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 4) {
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOLORING;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Coloring only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 5) {
                hairCuts++;
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_COL;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut and Coloring: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 6) {
                hairCuts++;
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 7) {
                permanents++;
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOL_PERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Coloring and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 8) {
                hairCuts++;
                colorings++;
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM_COL;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("haircut, Coloring, and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 9) {
                printReport();
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    
    public void resetTotals() {
        hairCuts = 0;
        permanents = 0;
        colorings = 0;
        customers = 0;
        dailyRev = 0;
        dailyTax = 0;
    }
    
    public void printReport() {
        if (customers == 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Daily Report for Salon");
        System.out.println("Number of Customers: $" + customers);
        System.out.println("Number of Hair Cuts: $" + hairCuts);
        System.out.println("Number of Permanents: $" + permanents);
        System.out.println("Number of Colorings: $" + colorings);
    
        System.out.println("Average amount spent per customer(Not including Tax): $" + (total / customers));
        System.out.println("Total Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
        System.out.println("Total Tax: $" + dailyTax);
        if (dailyRev >= 650) {
            System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $" + (dailyRev * 0.05));
            System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + 1.05 * dailyRev);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $0");
            System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet to your Salon class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Salon salon=new Salon();
   salon.menu();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Saloon {
    /* See example report */
    //Globals
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int hairCuts = 0;
    int permanents = 0;
    int colorings = 0;
    int customers = 0;
    
    double dailyRev = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double dailyTax = 0;
    double bonus; //money due the manager if certain conditions are met
    
    final double COSTHC = 20;  //Cost of HairCut
    final double COSTPERM = 50;  //Cost of Permanent
    final double COSTCOLORING = 60;  //Cost of Coloring
    final double COSTHC_PERM = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Permanent
    final double COSTCOL_PERM = (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Perm and Coloring
    final double COSTHC_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Haircut and Coloring
    final double COSTHC_PERM_COL = (COSTHC * 0.85) + (COSTPERM * 0.85) + (COSTCOLORING * 0.85);  //Cost of Cut, Perm and Color
    
    public void menu() {
        //preconditions:  none
        //postconditions: the correct method is called depending on the user's
        //input, totalValues are updated appropriately
        
        
        do {
            System.out.println("---------MENU---------");
            System.out.println("1 =  Reset Daily Totals");
            System.out.println("2 =  Haircut Only");
            System.out.println("3 =  Permanent Only");
            System.out.println("4 =  Coloring Only");
            System.out.println("5 =  Haircut and Coloring");
            System.out.println("6 =  Haircut and Permanent");
            System.out.println("7 =  Permanent and Coloring");
            System.out.println("8 =  Haircut, Permanent and Coloring");
            System.out.println("9 =  Print Daily Report");
            System.out.println("10 = Exit");
            
            
            int choice;
            choice = input.nextInt();
            
            // if (choice == 10) {
            //     System.exit(0);
            // }
    
            if (choice == 1) {
                resetTotals();
    
            }
            if (choice == 2) {
                hairCuts++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 3) {
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTPERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Permanent only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 4) {
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOLORING;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Coloring only: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 5) {
                hairCuts++;
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_COL;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut and Coloring: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 6) {
                hairCuts++;
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Haircut and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 7) {
                permanents++;
                colorings++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTCOL_PERM;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("Coloring and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 8) {
                hairCuts++;
                colorings++;
                permanents++;
                customers++;
                dailyRev = dailyRev + COSTHC_PERM_COL;
                dailyTax = 0.07 * dailyRev;
                total = dailyRev + dailyTax;
                System.out.println("haircut, Coloring, and Permanent: $");
                System.out.println("Charge: $" + dailyRev);
                System.out.println("Tax: $" + dailyTax);
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    
            }
            if (choice == 9) {
                printReport();
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    
    public void resetTotals() {
        hairCuts = 0;
        permanents = 0;
        colorings = 0;
        customers = 0;
        dailyRev = 0;
        dailyTax = 0;
    }
    
    public void printReport() {
        if (customers == 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Daily Report for Salon");
        System.out.println("Number of Customers: $" + customers);
        System.out.println("Number of Hair Cuts: $" + hairCuts);
        System.out.println("Number of Permanents: $" + permanents);
        System.out.println("Number of Colorings: $" + colorings);
    
        System.out.println("Average amount spent per customer(Not including Tax): $" + (total / customers));
        System.out.println("Total Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
        System.out.println("Total Tax: $" + dailyTax);
        if (dailyRev >= 650) {
            System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $" + (dailyRev * 0.05));
            System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + 1.05 * dailyRev);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Manager Bonus: $0");
            System.out.println("Total Net Revenues: $" + dailyRev);
        }
    }
}


public class Salon{

     public static void main(String []args){
         
       Saloon s = new Saloon();
      s.menu();
     }
}
```

Comment: you can just copy this code and run  your file

Answer (score -3):

you can create another main class below this class

also remove public from Salon Class
and rename class Salon to Saloon

```
public class Saloon()
{
     public static void main(String args[]){

      //Now create an object of class above 
      Saloon s1 = new Saloon();

     // Now call the method you want
     s1.menu(); 


     }


}
```

Comment: `class main()` doesnt seem to be proper syntax for java? In any case his file is named `Salon.java` so that wouldnt compile btw

Comment: Is putting parenthesis after `Salon` or whatever the class name a new feature in java? afaik that is a syntax error? 

Also you instantiate a `Saloon` instead of a `Salon`.

Comment: salon() means you have created an object of class

Comment: Why bother to create a separate class just to hold the main()? I just put it as part of the main class. But you're right about the spelling.

Comment: you can write clean code not much things in main class

Comment: It's not any cleaner to create a new class just for the main().

Comment: depends upon you